# Loading the file only once in application

Tags: python-3.x, cache

I have json data in a file and I want to load the file content only once when application is initiated instead of calling the loading file multiple times in class instances.

I created a config which loads on app init named `REPOSITORY_CONFIG`.

Then created a script with the method like this:

```
import json

CACHE = None

def get_repo_config():
    global CACHE
    with open('config.json') as config_json:
        CACHE = json.load(config_json)
    return CACHE
```

I have `config.py`

```
REPOSITORY_CONFIG = CACHE if CACHE else get_repo_config
```

This config is used in a class method like this:

```
import REPOSITORY_CONFIG

class Test():

  def check_config():
    config_data = REPOSITORY_CONFIG
```

Is there any other way to do this or I am not following right approach?

Comment: It looks like `REPOSITORY_CONFIG` is a dict, so `import REPOSITORY_CONFIG` doesn't make sense. Is it supposed to be `import config` and then `config_data = config.REPOSITORY_CONFIG`?

Answer (score 1):

Module level code is only executed the first time a module is imported. Subsequent imports return the already imported module without rerunning the module level code. So use top level code to load the json file. Something like:

```
# config.py

# this module level code only gets run the first time the module is
# imported.
with open('config.json') as config_json:
    REPOSITORY_CONFIG = json.load(config_json)

# ... other config stuff ...
```

Then it can be used like:

```
import config

class Test():

    def check_config():
        config_data = config.REPOSITORY_CONFIG
```